# what should be done to keep PR2 stationary on a ramp?

Tags: gazebo, urdf, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

In Gazebo simulation, the PR2 goes down a ramp due to gravity ; I assume the wheel base controller still applies 0 velocity for the wheels.
How should I keep PR2 stationary? What changes should be made in the base controller, URDF, transmission?

Thanks in advance.

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31548/what-should-be-done-to-keep-pr2-stationary-on-a-ramp?/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-04-15**:
if the command velocity is applied continuously, PR2 will move on the ramp but why can't I stop it on the ramp? any suggestions please.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-04-17**:
actually my original question is to move a custom robot on a terrain. But, first I tried moving it on a ramp. and it just goes down due to gravity and it is same with the PR2 on a ramp. I hope someone who has worked on robots on a terrain could help me. Thanks.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-12-27**:
The PR2 does this in real life too. On the real PR2, turning the casters sideways usually stops it, but it's unstable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5153/can-we-lock-or-freeze-a-moving-joint/ answers the question.

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2013-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0